# Success callback not executed in cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation

Tags: background, geolocation, cordova-plugins

I need to store device location in firebase database every 30 sec. I am using `cordova - 7.0.1` and `cordova-android - 6.2.3` and https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation/tree/v2.3.2. I have two questions.
1. The success callbacks are not getting executed when app is in foreground. Not even once.

```
backgroundGeolocation.configure(getLocation, errorLocation, {
        desiredAccuracy: 10,      
        stationaryRadius: 10,
        distanceFilter: 10,
        locationProvider: 'ANDROID_ACTIVITY_PROVIDER',
        interval: 10000,      
        fastestInterval: 5000,      
        stopOnStillActivity: false,
        debug: true,      
        stopOnTerminate: false
      });
```

This is the configuration that I am using. what should I do to make it work ??
2. Is it possible to pass parameters to success callback function

```
 var getLocation = function(location, param1, param2) {
      console.log('[js] getLoaction:'+ location.latitude +','+ location.longitude +'-'+new Date());
      backgroundGeolocation.finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this plugin not-so-straightforward to use, but I see a few things in your example that could be causing your lack of a callback:

*locationProvider* is a numeric value; the examples use enumerations for ANDROID_ACTIVITY_PROVIDER, which is actually a numeric value of 1. You might try using that over the string value of 'ANDROID_ACTIVITY_PROVIDER' and see if that helps. It's possible the plugin can't find the provider you're trying to use, so no callbacks happen.

Your chosen configuration values for *distanceFilter* and *stationaryRadius* may be preventing the device you're using from generating any callbacks for you. I found changing these to 0 in development and going from there helped my device generate more GPS callbacks and if they were set too high, nothing happened even with me running around with my device and jumping up and down in my office like an idiot.

Also, inside your *getLocation* function, you're turning off the library by calling finish(). This would result in you getting one single callback before the plugin turned itself off. So if you get to the point where your callback is being called, you will want to change that so that they continue to happen.